# Call Javascript on Sharepoint Calendar add button Click

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, visual-web-part

How to call JavaScript in SharePoint Calendar Add Button Click event ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can hook into the button, for example with jQuery: `$('[id="Ribbon.Calendar.Events.New.NewListItem-Large"]').click(function(){...})` or even override the methods directly in _SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarMouseHandler_. But this will only tell you if the modal window were opened. You could however override the whole modal

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ms-acal-rootdiv').unbind("click").click(function () {
       ....
    });
}); i tried this but its not working

Comment: $('[id="Ribbon.Calendar.Events.New.NewListItem-Large"]').click(function(){...})‌​                               its also not working

Comment: Note that will only trigger for the large button (hence "NewListItem-Large"). You can run that in console when you see the button. document ready will not work, as the Ribbon is loaded asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do instead is to use [`PreSaveAction`](http://replicrux.com/2011/11/09/validating-forms-in-sharepoint.aspx). You need to append this to the form where you save the item, and run it like this when the form is ready:

```
function PreSaveAction() {
  // Do work;
  return shouldSaveItem;
}
```

For example (jQuery):

```
$(function() {
  window.PreSaveAction = function() { return false; };
});
```